# Creating a PFX file from clear text cer and pem files

Tags: ssl, openssl, pem, pfx, cer

I have downloaded the latest openSSL, and have two files, a cer file and a pem file, both in clear text.

pem file:

Subject: CN=subdomain.domain.com,OU=User,O=ORC PKI,C=US
Issuer: CN=IssueName NFI CA 6,O=ORC PKI,C=US
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
text
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

cer file:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
text
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

I need to convert these into a single .pfx file so I can sign documents, but I've tried a number of variants suggested in other questions, and they give me errors.  Does anyone have any idea how to make this work?

Joshua Sharf

Among the things I've tried:

openssl pkcs12 -export -out domain.pfx -inkey domain.cer.txt -in domain.pem.txt

Stripping the Subject & Issuer information from the pem.txt file
Reversing .pem and .cer between the -inkey and -in

None of these works.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to convert these into a single .pfx file so I can sign documents, ...

Based on your question your have two certificates (`... BEGIN CERTIFICATE ...`) but no private key. But for signing a private key is needed, which you don't provide. That's why it cannot work.